# Undefined class error, jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble getting the `addClass()` jQuery method to work - when I try to add the class (`highlight`, see below) to some of the paragraphs I've created in `index.html` I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: highlight is not defined`. Can someone help me figure out why?

`application.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var newPara = $('<p>Hi Zhilin! This must be pretty boring for you.</p>');   
    $('#greeting-button').on('click', function(){
        $('h1').append(newPara);
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $('#odd-button').on('click', function(){
        $('.odd-p').addClass(highlight);
    });
});
```

`style3.css`:

```
h1 {
    color: red;
}

.highlight {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Relevant portion on `index.html`:

```
<p class="even-p">I'm an odd paragraph.</p>
<p class="odd-p">I'm an even paragraph.</p>
<p class="even-p">I'm an odd paragraph.</p>
<p class="odd-p">I'm an even paragraph.</p>
<button id="odd-button">Click to highlight odd paragraphs</button>
<button id="even-button">Click to highlight even paragraphs</button>
```

Comment: you have to use `.addClass('highlight');` with quotes

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime in jquery you will be referring to ids,classes(elements in general) they will be in quotation marks between the parenthesis.